# How to create a voronoi animation for moving points in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, voronoi

I'm trying to create an animated movie from tracking data for a set of points - 5 points.

**Dataset Format**

*The x,y coordinates for the 5 points are in a Pandas dataframe with a total of 10 columns - **each pair of columns are the x,y coordinates for a point at any given time**. Each row gives the position of the point after 1/10th of a second.* A sample would look like this -

```
   x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4  x5  y5
0   1   3   2   1   9   1   1   1   8   1
1   5   7   5   5   7   5   5   8   4   5
2   7   1   7   9   7   5   4   8   0   7
3   3   5   4   6   3   6   9   7   3   0
```

**Plotting Function**

The function I've used to create an animation from the points is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.read_csv(file)


def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
    scat.set_offsets(([dff.iloc[i,0], dff.iloc[i,1]], [dff.iloc[i,2],dff.iloc[i,3]], [dff.iloc[i,4],dff.iloc[i,5]], [dff.iloc[i,6],dff.iloc[i,7]], [dff.iloc[i,8],dff.iloc[i,9]]))


    return scat,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs = (fig, scat),
                               frames = len(dff.index)-1, interval = 100)
```

That works for me without any issues. However, I want to now create a Voronoi animation out of the points. I thought it would be as simple as just adding this to the plotting function after importing from `scipy.spatial`:

```
vor = Voronoi(points) ##points are the rows of the `df`
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
```

However, that didn't work out. There weren't any errors but nothing changed. I'm led to believe that creating an animation is slightly more complicated than what I tried.

The final output I have in mind would be very similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAz9mDlsWgQ)(more points, of course).
How can I create an animation using matplotlib? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this looks reminiscent of what you're looking for. Let me know if I'm on the right lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
   x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4  x5  y5
0   1   3   2   1   9   1   1   1   8   1
1   5   7   5   5   7   5   5   8   4   5
2   7   1   7   9   7   5   4   8   0   7
3   3   5   4   6   3   6   9   7   3   0"""),
sep='\s+')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.set_xlim(df.iloc[:, ::2].values.min(),
            df.iloc[:, ::2].values.max())
ax.set_ylim(df.iloc[:, 1::2].values.min(),
            df.iloc[:, 1::2].values.max())

def updater(i):
    ax.cla()
    ax.scatter(df.iloc[i, ::2], df.iloc[i, 1::2])
    vor = Voronoi(np.vstack((df.iloc[i, ::2], df.iloc[i, 1::2])).T)
    voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax=ax)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updater, 
                               frames=df.shape[0], interval=1000)
```

Comment: I run your code in google colab but nothing moves. Is it suppose to be moving? ho can really make it animation?

Comment: [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lnl5UPFWVPrryaZZgEzd0theI6S94c3X#scrollTo=QLRBwgFqdr83) is an example for animations in colab. Since colab cannot show interactive figures (what you see are static png images) you essentially need to create some javascript object first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked for me. I had a few questions. Firstly, I want different points to be of different sizes and colours. In my animation, I was passing an array of size and color like this - `scat.set_color(np.array(["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "k"]))`. However, now that doesn't have the intended effect so what's happening? 
Secondly, I am also trying to add some lines, like so - `ax.plot([1,2],[4,5])` and those don't work either. 
Also, I added `plt.cla()` at the beginning of the function to clear out the Voronoi from the previous iteration.

Comment: Also, thank you for showing me a more Pythonic way to get the list of points to be plotted.

Comment: I think it's the `ax.cla()` which is removing the other lines, points etc from being plotted after the function is being called (although why, I don't understand, because I'm plotting them after the function is called). That still leaves me with the problem of not being able to set size, color properties to the scatter plot within the function.